# Is it possible in MySQL to apply the cascading deletion of a late added foreign key to remove lose records in a child table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, rdbms, cascading-deletes

I have a big MySQL database that used no foreign keys. I have to sanitize the DB now (as far as possible). So I will add `FOREIGN KEY`'s with `ON DELETE CASCADE` on some places.

This works for newly created rows. But since the database is old there exists a lot of "lost" records already ("lost" meaning child table has rows which reference non-existing/deleted parent table rows and thus can never be found because the join/where constraint happens on the reference field between child and parent). I could delete them with a `JOIN` between parent and child tables, or with a `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, but if it's somehow possible I'd like to have the DBMS do it by itself, since it now has the foreign keys anyways and doing it manually would be much more error prone and slow.

Is it possible to let a late-added cascade delete enabled foreign key delete already existing lost records in MySQL?

Comment: `ON DELETE CASCADE` should work with old rows when you delete them. Are you talking about rows that were deleted before you added the foreign key? That should prevent you from adding the foreign key in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar I successfully added the key in the child table while having referenced but deleted rows in the parent. It did not delete obsolete child rows and did not throw any error, but the key was there.

Comment: Do you have foreign key checking disabled? It should have thrown an error. Anyway, I don't think there's an automatic way to delete the orphaned records, you'll need to do it with an explicit `DELETE` query.

Comment: Please explain '"lost" records'. Putting quotes around things that don't mean what you mean does not make them mean what you mean. Please give DDL. Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: @philipxy I just explained "lost", even though it should be clear for someone who reads the whole question. What would be an example here? I'm asking if MySQL has a possibility to do something. That's like asking for an example from someone who asks if "pointers are possible in PHP?" How should I provide an example if I do not know if it's possible at all?